# isset ($_POST['submit']) not working

Tags: php, html, forms, isset

I tried a lot to find a solution to this problem but I am not sure what's the actual issue here. 
I have done similar exercises before and it worked perfect but this code is not working at all.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$database=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','manager')
or die ('didn\'t work');
$in=$_POST['income'];
$sv=$_POST['savings'];
echo $in;
echo $sv;
mysqli_query($database,"USE manager");
mysqli_query($database,"INSERT INTO manage (m1,m2) VALUES ('$_POST[income]','$_POST[savings]')");
mysqli_close($database);
}

?>


<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
Enter your monthly income
<input type="text" name="income" >

Enter your target savings

<input type="text" name="savings" >

<input type="submit" >
</form>
```

Ruled Out Possibilities:

1. Form is not getting submitted
   I used `method='get'` and confirmed that form is getting submitted.
2. Not an issue with db name or table name.
   Figured this out because no such error was shown and content in 'die()' wasn't echoed.

What I think is the issue?

> Control is not moving inside the `if block` even if form is submitted. I am not able to figure out why this is happening. Other forms are working perfect. The problem exists with this code only. I learned the code from online tutorials and has used it before.

Comment: You have no inputs with the name `submit`.

Comment: Oh. Got it. I may delete this post then. Cannot imagine I made that mistake.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JonStirling

Comment: don't go live with this, btw

Comment: error reporting would have been of help also.

Comment: @Fred-ii- New to Php and forms. :) Won't happen again. Never knew `isset` used name. I had been thinking it's the type that `isset` looks for.

Comment: @MathewsMathai hehe no problemo. Usually best to have a "Plan-B", such as `if/else{...}` that way, if it goes to the "else" part, you'll know something failed.